# Karate : how to add if condition on match contains deep

Tags: karate

```
* print refJson
* match response contains deep refJson
```

I want to execute the below command (execute java code ) if match failed . Please let me know how to handle such thing

```
* def initJava = Java.type ('com.MathCalc')
```

Comment: @PeterThomas  since its comparision on two josn. i need to used * match json1 contains deep json2   And can not used  function as * def var = karate.match()

Comment: if the links above don't help - then please assume that what you are asking for is not supported by karate